# Get values from JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

How do I get the message and status values from this response

```
{"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}
```

I've tried:

```
data.message
data['errors'].message
data[0].message

data.status
data[0].status
```

Edit:

I am parsing a res like this

```
 var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery(res).find('#container').text());

 console.log(data.status);
 console.log(data.errors[0].message);
```

The string I'm parsing is:

```
"{\"errors\":[{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"Invalid login details\"}],\"status\":\"failure\"}"
```

**Answer:**

The response I was getting was already being encoded as JSON, so once I made it a plain echo and kept the parsing on the client side via js and stripped the slashes from the res it now works as expected. Thank you all for commenting as it helped me a lot figure out what I was doing wrong

Comment: Errors is an array with one element.

Comment: have you tried data.errors[0].message?

Comment: data.status = undefined

Comment: data.errors[0].message = Can't read property '0' of undefined

Comment: try adding `console.log(typeof data)` and see what you have. I'm guessing it might be a string

Comment: yea it's coming back as a string :( so why isn't it parsing as a JSON obj when I'm parsing it?

Answer (score 0):

Errors is an array so you need to access it by index.

```js
const data = {"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}

console.log(
  data.errors[0].code,
  data.errors[0].message,
  data.status
)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, are you sure that you have an object and not just a JSON string? you may need to call JSON.parse(data);

then it looks like you're looking for `data.errors[0].code` or `data.errors[0].message` or `data.status`

Comment: var data = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery(res).find('#container').text());

              console.log(data.status);

              console.log(data.errors[0].message);

Comment: have you confirmed that `jQuery(res).find('#container').text()` equals what you think?

Comment: yea I get the response I want which is parsed correctly as shown above with the JSON obj

Comment: "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":3,\"message\":\"Invalid login details\"}],\"status\":\"failure\"}"

Comment: try using `JSON.parse` instead of `jQuery.parseJSON`. I've never heard of the jQuery parse

Comment: I'm assuming that's the log before you parse it

Comment: I have when I saw your comment but same outcome

Comment: yea the string with slashes is before parsing

Comment: it's working here https://jsfiddle.net/h2fpsxus/

Comment: I've moved the res string to it's own var to follow the same format as in your fiddle and then added that to JSON.parse(var) but still getting the same outcome, don't know why as it should be straight forward. Must be missing something

Comment: After the JSON.parse(var) I'm logging the typeof and it's coming back as a string

Comment: hit update and send me the fiddle link

Comment: I can't update your fiddle as the string I'm getting is an Ajax res from a WP site; the response is sending back the full page DOM therefore I'm doing the .find() on the res to get the JSON string I need which I want to use to show various messages based on the status etc. As I say after the JSON.parse() it's still saying it's a string, I've also tried JSON.stringify() on the string before the JSON.parse() as well